# Finding point on line closest to other point: unexpected results

Tags: qgis, spatialite, qspatialite

I'm basically trying to do the same thing as outlined here: [Finding the point closest to a point on a near feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99779/finding-the-point-closest-to-a-point-on-a-near-feature)

However, the results I'm getting with the queries suggested in the [accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/99793/70696) don't make sense. Here's a screenshot of (a part of) my data, a bunch of points and lines:

[image]

The first step is to find the line closest to a given point:

```
select "p"."id"  pid, 
"l"."id"  lid, 
min(Distance("p"."geom","l"."geom")) as distance
from "net_clipped" p, "ver01_l_clipped" l
group by pid
order by pid;
```

The results contain only one line id and the distance seems to be wrong:

```
pid    lid       distance
1      724       3.19983e+07
2      724       3.19995e+07
... and so on
```

The actual distance of the points to the next line should be just a few meters.

The data came from two shape files that I imported into a spatialite database using QGIS' database manager. They look fine in both QGIS 2.14 and ArcMap 10.3. I'm running the queries with QSpatiaLite.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Are the two layers in the same CRS?

Comment: Good point, they weren't. Looks better now!