# Drawing lines to nearest points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, proximity, polyline-creation

I have two point layers, one with telecom towers and another with secondary schools. I have used the NNJoin Plugin to find the nearest tower from each school, and calculated the distance between. The result is in a vector layer, with separate columns for the tower and school names.

How can one draw lines between the pairs of points?

Comment: Do the pairs of points have a feature in common? (for example an ID) It can used as a key to link them...

Comment: No, they have separate IDs, i.e. each school and tower has a separate name, and (obviously) separate lat/long. But since each pair is uniquely defined on each row in the table, perhaps I can create a unique ID by concatenating school name and tower name?

Answer (score 10):

This should be possible without any plugin using the default Processing tools, particularly **Distance to nearest hub**:

[image]

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisdistancetonearesthublinetohub

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume we have eight features in `'school'` (blue squares) and five in `'tower'` (orange circles) accordingly, see image below.

[image: Example]

With the following Query, it is possible *to draw lines between the pairs of points.*

```sql
SELECT s.Name AS SName, t.Name AS TName,
       make_line(s.geometry, t.geometry),
       ROUND(MIN(ST_Distance(s.geometry, t.geometry)),2) AS distance,
       s.id || '_' || t.id AS uniqueid
FROM school AS s, tower AS t
GROUP BY s.Name
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

The output Virtual Layer will generate shortest lines between schools and towers including the following attributes `"school name"`, `"closest tower name"`, `"distance to the closest tower"` and `"unique id"`.

[image: Result]

---

**References:**

- [Finding point closest to point on near feature?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99779/finding-point-closest-to-point-on-near-feature)
- [PostGIS nearest points with ST_Distance, kNN](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136403/postgis-nearest-points-with-st-distance-knn)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, exactly since QGIS version 3.16, there is another possibility: use the overlay functions of QGIS expressions, either with [Geometry Generator or Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814). Use this expression:

```
make_line (
    $geometry,
    overlay_nearest (
        'towers',
        $geometry
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: red= schools, white=towers; the black lines (arrows) are created with the expression from above:*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish this. I used the following method.

1. Use the NN_join plugin to find the shortest distance between a school and a tower.
2. Use the vector/geometry tools/add geometry attributes to add coordinate values for the point pairs to the file.
3. Export as `.csv`, and open in Excel. Sort the file and add a row number as `"ID"`.
4. Split the file in two, one with school points and another with the associated tower. Keep the sorting sequence, and add row number as `"ID"` in the second file.
5. Now search for the following plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/connect_points/ 
   *Note:* This plugin is not updated for QGIS 3.x, so I used QGIS 2.8 for this step.
6. Import the schools and towers layers and run the plugin.

The result is a `shp`-layer with lines from each school to the nearest tower.