# Find 3 closest points in relation to another point

Tags: qgis, point, distance

Using QGIS, I have two shapefiles:

- points representing enterprises (about 50k)
- points representing towers (about 300)

For each enterprise, I need to figure out the three closest towers and their distances in meters.

Is there a script I can run that can calculate this? Or do I need to use the field calculator/select by location tool?

Comment: may be interested in this article [Drawing lines to nearest point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322474/drawing-lines-to-nearest-point)

Answer (score 4):

To complement the other answer of using Distance Matrix Tool, a worked example is included. For instance, if you have your two point shapefiles loaded as follows (entreprises and towers loaded - nb sample data generated for example): 
[image]

Then open the Distance Matrix tool (`Vector --> Analsyis Tools --> Distance Matrix`) as follows. First, select the entreprises as your input and specify the unique id for each entreprise feature. Your `towers` will be the target layer and you can then specify the nearest neighbours as 3:

[image]

If it completes successfully, a new point shap file will be loaded to the canvas with the distance results stored between the 3 nearest points:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Distance Matrix tool. Input 1 is the enterprise, input 2 is the towers.

Comment: Though technically correct, your answer lacks depth. In the future, please add some more details when answer, maybe even a screenshot.