# Connecting lines with point in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, point, line, proximity

I have two shapefiles

1. Blue network
2. yellow locations

as shown in the below figure.

I want to connect all yellow dots with the blue lines blue as shown in red color in the figure.

Is there a way to connect all the yellow circles (buildings) to blues lines(roads)?

[image]

Comment: Have your researched enough your issue? By any means it is not a new topic on GIS SE. For instance, I may refer you to these threads: [Joining attributes from points to lines QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336049/joining-attributes-from-points-to-lines-qgis/), [Joining attributes from nearest point in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/joining-attributes-from-nearest-point-in-qgis), [Moving points onto lines (~neighborhood)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45123/moving-points-onto-lines-neighborhood) etc.

Comment: As well as [Finding distance between buildings and nearest road using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324577/finding-distance-between-buildings-and-nearest-road-using-qgis/) and [Nearest distance between point and line layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/nearest-distance-between-point-and-line-layers-in-qgis/). Probably the last one is what you need, please pay attention to [@Joseph's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181726/99589).

Comment: @Taras. Yes. I already searched the answers and tried to use NNJoin plugin and also MMQGIS to connect the dots with the nearest road. But it is not working. I am quite new to QGIS and not aware of much options.

Comment: Can you add those things (i.s. your efforts and current results) into the question, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not taking any attributes into account (for example road name stored in each address point), just finds closest road using [closestSegmentWithContext](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#aaa0c911cb37cc33dd024662ec314fdae). Then you can merge (or spatial join etc.) output lines with your roads.

```py
roadlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('TR_ROAD')[0]
addrlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ADDRESS')[0]

#List all features
adresses = [f for f in addrlyr.getFeatures()]
roads = [f for f in roadlyr.getFeatures()] 

#Create empty vector layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(roadlyr.crs().authid()), "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

#For each adress find closest road
for adress in adresses:
    closest_road = min([road.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext(adress.geometry().asPoint()) for road in roads], key=lambda x: x[0]) #Find which road is closest to current address. Index 0 is the distance
    gLine = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(adress.geometry().asPoint()), QgsPoint(closest_road[1])]) #Index 1 is the PointXY geometry of the closest road location
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(gLine)
    provider.addFeature(f)


QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

[image]